# Constrain element to parent after drop with pep

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on an image dropper to manipulate (resize/crop) the image using pep.
Got it working to drag and drop on top of the container but when this is happening the element should be constrained to the parent (editor).
Tried via rest/stop but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

`[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MaartenTe/z9qusuqc/ "Jsfiddle")`

Comment: have you tried, $('.pep').pep({  constrainTo: 'parent' });?

Comment: That makes it constrained to the original container. It should be on the panel after dragging it to it.